# Add check box value to total using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a number of sliders which when moved add values to a total (these are variables `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`, `eee` and `fff` - the total is variable `total`).

I would also like to add the values of a check box to the total when the check box is checked.

I have come up with the below, however, this doesn't add anything to var `total`. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

```
// base total value
var total = $("#total").val("100");

$("#priceg").click(
  function() {
    var ggg = 0;
    $('#priceg:checked').each(function() {
      ggg += parseInt($(this).val());
    });

    // add ggg to total
    total.val(+100 + +aaa + +bbb + +ccc + +ddd + +eee + +fff + +ggg);
  }
);
```

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="priceg" id="priceg" value="100" />
```

Comment: Check your console next time !

Comment: Do you have more than one checkbox? As it stands now, your code is overly complicated. Why iterate over *one* checkbox with `$().each`? You can replace that whole construct with `var ggg = this.checked ? +this.value : 0;`.

Comment: do we need to have `+ +` before each adding? Or just 1 `+` is enough

Comment: @KhanhTO: If the variables could be strings, then you have to convert them to numbers first, otherwise the  "addition" would be string concatenation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
  $('#priceg:checked').each(function() {
      ggg += parsInt($(this).val());
    });
```

to

```
  $('#priceg:checked').each(function() {
      ggg += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
```

error at parsInt()

**UPDATE**

Define them outside like this

```
$(function() {    
    // inital values
    var total = $("#total").val("100");
    var aaa = 0;
    var bbb = 0;
```

and change this event

```
$('#checkbox').change(function(){
    aaa = parseInt(aaa);
    this.checked ? total.val(100  +aaa  +parseInt(this.value)) : total.val(aaa +100);
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/8R7NW/7/)

Comment: `var total = $("#total").val("100");` is perfectly fine.

Comment: If you call `.val` with an argument, the value of the selected elements is changed and it returns again a jQuery object. Only if you call `.val` *without* an argument, the value will be returned, not a jQuery object.

Comment: THanks, Anton. This looks good. But for some reason I get a NaN when the checkbox is checked first (i.e. before the slider is moved). And also, when the checkbox is unchecked, the 100 remains added.

Comment: do var aaa = 0; var bbb=0; and for the unchecking you need to make a function for that too

Comment: Ok thanks this works great. The only problem is when the checkbox is checked first - the value is still not added.

Comment: @user2726041 If this was the solution don't forget to accept this as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You are defining your variables locally

```
var ggg = 0;
```

if you do the same with the rest (`aaa`,`bbb`,..) => you don't have access to `aaa`, `bbb`, `ccc`, `ddd`, `eee` and `fff`

Comment: Could you show me what you mean? I have created a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/8R7NW/2/

Answer (score 0):

parsInt should be parseInt you have a typo

Comment: THanks - I have corrected the typo, but am still experiencing the problem.